# PHP sees a MYSQL query as a string

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find the int value of the latest id from my blog post database or use the one provided by GET. If I manually enter the GET into the URL, when I try `echo 'current id='.$current_id;`, the GET will echo the number but if there is no GET variable, it will echo `current id=SELECT max(id) FROM posts;`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $current_id = $_GET['id'];
  }
else{
  $current_id = 'SELECT max(id) FROM posts';
}
```

Why does PHP think this is a string?

Comment: it thinks it's a string because it is a string. you have to execute query, and then extract id from the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute query like this:

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//MySqli Select Query
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT max(id) FROM posts");

if($result !== false ) { //$mysqli->query() returns false on failure 

// query is ok

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//get id from database
$id = (int)$result['id'];

} else {
// query failed, handle errors
}



?>
```

Comment: Oh I see, I was trying to use normal MySQL connection but I recently changed over to PDO. I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a string.

You need to connect to a database and then execute query.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $current_id = $_GET['id'];
}
else{
    $query = 'SELECT max(id) FROM posts';
    $current_id = $conn->query($query);
}
```

Comment: your example $current_id = $conn->query($querry)  will not return desired value... This is from PHP manual : Mysqli::query Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Answer (score -2):

Latest `id` can be a time stamp `2015-02-18 16:53:00`, or a column called `id` with an incremented unique value.  You need to determine what identifies a blog entry as "latest" and then make the appropriate query.